# Why I am getting UMR(unInitialized Memory Read)Error in following code snippet

Tags: c++

Why I am getting UMR(unInitialized Memory Read)Error in following code snippet.
I am getting UMR error while calling copy constructor of derived class

```
class base{
public :

    base(int);
    int id;

    int getid()
    {
        return id;
    }
};

base::base(int a)
{
    id = a;
}

class derived:public base{
public :
    derived(derived &);
    int inum;

    int getnum()
    {
        return inum;
    }

};

derived::derived(derived &d):base(d.getnum()) // UMR Error
{
    inum = id;
}
```

Can anybody have any idea what is wrong with the implementation?

Comment: For sure you need to add brackets in the line causing the error: d.getnum()

Comment: I am not talking about compilation error , This is error of Memory Error and yes i am getting error at line i have commented .If i pass zero in place of `d.getnum()` then it would not show any UMR error.Yes there is braces , i forget to write in code.

Comment: Please show how you use those classes. Because right now you never actually initialize the member variables in the derived class (i.e. you read from uninitialized memory). Read http://sscce.org/ for tips on creating example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can compile your code, a few issues dressed below:

```
class derived:class base{
               ^^^-> public
```

should be:

```
class derived : public base
```

change `int getnum();` `to int getnum() const;`

```
derived::derived(derived &d):base(d.getnum) // UMR Error
                                         ^^^ function call?
```

why initialize base::id with derived::inum?

should be:

```
   derived::derived(const derived &d) : base(d) // initialize base with base
   {
                    ^^^  copy constructor has const 
      inum = d.inum;  // initialize derived member
      // inum = id;  why you assign id back to inum again?
   }
```

Comment: yes , you are this code have some syntax errors but i was just trying to point out UMR problem .Why it is UMR to call function `d.getnum()` in copy constructor of derived class

Answer (score 1):

You derived class never initialize `inum` variable. Error message said it to you. `d.getnum()` returns uninitialized `inum` variable.